# displaying time in microsecond precision in tshark

Tags: wireshark, tshark

It's possible in Wireshark (View -> Time Display Formats -> Microseconds), see attached image
[Wireshark settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/canN2.png). Can somebody please share how to do this via tshark? I can see there are "-t" and "-u" options and they take care of some bits of date-time formatting but not second precision part.
I need this to automate some workflow. I get capture files having both micro and nano seconds, but filtered text output must be normalized.

Answer (score 0):

If your capture file contains timestamps of such precision, `-t a` could print it, see my example:

```
% tshark -r packetcapture.cap -t a
    1 10:23:40.232514 192.168.3.140 → 192.168.1.1  TLSv1.2     0   Application Data
    2 10:23:40.232524  192.168.1.1 → 192.168.3.140 TCP     0   443 → 60152 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=77 Win=514 Len=0 TSval=1643984880 TSecr=1054195834
    3 10:23:40.232785  192.168.1.1 → 192.168.3.140 TLSv1.2     0   Application Data
    4 10:23:40.235273 192.168.3.140 → 192.168.1.1  TCP     0   60152 → 443 [ACK] Seq=77 Ack=7095 Win=1937 Len=0 TSval=1054195837 TSecr=1643984880
    5 10:23:40.235594 192.168.3.140 → 192.168.1.1  TCP     0   [TCP Window Update] 60152 → 443 [ACK] Seq=77 Ack=7095 Win=2048 Len=0 TSval=1054195837 TSecr=1643984880
```

Other formats described in [tshark man](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) page.